# Is the function below continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology and $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\}$:
>   $$f(x)= \begin{cases}0 &\text{if }x<0,\\ 1 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

**My attempt:**

$\{1\}\subset\{0,1\}$ is an open set (as it belongs to the discrete topology), $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is not an open set, then, since $f^{-1}(\{1\})=[0,\infty)$, $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks perfectly fine. In fact you can also cross check with your $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. The subspace topology on $\{ 0, 1 \}$ induced from ${\mathbb{R}}$ is also discrete. So $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition would also work: take $\epsilon = 1/4$. If $f$ is continuous at $x_0 = 0$ then there must be be some $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $-\delta < x < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq 1/4$. The last inequality is precisely $3/4 < f(x) < 5/4$. Now for $x = - \delta/2$, we have $f(x) = 0$. A contradiction.